# How to pass parameters to a jQuery plugin which "might" be related to the selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the following plugin to illustrate my question.  http://jsbin.com/vorahohali

How can I access the selected `id` element(s) within the plugin?

While I certainly can access the selected `<a>` using `this` within the plugin, the plugin needs to be able to be generically implemented using any value of `id` and all values in `param` should be defined outside the plugin.  For instance, `id` might not be related to the selected element such as `$('#MyID').val()`), or might be something related to the element but not always the same way such as `$(this).data('id')` or `$(this).parent().data('id')`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            (function($){
                var defaults = {param: {},};
                var methods = {
                    init : function (options) {
                        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                        return this.each(function () {
                            $(this).click(function(e) {
                                //How do I pass and receive settings.param.id
                                console.log(settings.param,settings.param.myInput,settings.param.id,settings.param.id());
                            });
                        });
                    },
                };

                $.fn.bla = function(method) {
                    if (methods[method]) {return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));}
                    else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);}
                        else {$.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.bla');}    
                };

                }(jQuery)
            );
            $(function(){
                $("a").bla({param:{id:function(){$(this).data('id')},myInput:$('#myInput').val()},});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="How do I get this value?">click</a>
        <input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="My Input Value" />
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Huh? The anchors that the plugin is running on would be `this` inside the plugin, and it's even prewrapped in jQuery ?

Comment: use 'this' inside the function

Comment: @adeneo  Anyway to do so from outside the plugin?  `id` will not necessary be tied to the element, and will be defined outside the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I took some stuff out of here that was confusing me, like the function for ID etc, but I got it working by swapping from just running .bla on all a tags to using .each() like

```
$('a').each(function(){$(this).bla(OPTIONS)});
```

http://jsbin.com/huyesanewa/edit?html,console,output

That way you're passing each .bla function the correct values

Comment: Thanks Caleb,  While it works, I don't think it is the "typical" way to pass valves on a plugin.  I would like to be able to do it without the `each()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but the best I came up with.  I would appreciate any constructive criticism.  Thanks
http://jsbin.com/zoqugiwohe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function($){
                var defaults = {param: {},};
                var methods = {
                    init : function (options) {
                        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                        return this.each(function () {
                            $(this).click(function(e) {
                                for (var elem in settings.param) {
                                    if (typeof settings.param[elem] === "function") {
                                        settings.param[elem]=settings.param[elem](this);
                                    }
                                }
                                console.log(settings.param);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                };

                $.fn.bla = function(method) {
                    if (methods[method]) {return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));}
                    else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);}
                        else {$.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.bla');}    
                };

                }(jQuery)
            );
            $(function(){
                $("a").bla({param:{id:function(t){return $(t).data('id')},myInput:$('#myInput').val()},});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="How do I get this value?">click</a>
        <input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="My Input Value" />
    </body> 
</html>
```